# Undefined method `omniauth' for Devise:Module (devise, omniauth, heroku, rails 3.0.3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, devise, amazon-web-services, omniauth

I have an app that uses Amazon Product Advertising API at local with no issues. In order to push it to Heroku, I have to change the version of the aws gem I use to make it work with Heroku ("treyconnell-ruby-aaws" v0.8.3) and that version limits me to Rails 3.0.3 and to devise v1.1.8 gems.

When I downgrade gems and 'bundle update', something breaks even at local, guessing omniauth and devise start fighting. The server fail to starts with the following error log.

I tried many different configurations of loading omniauth gem, oa-auth, requiring omniauth/oauth etc, still the same error. What might be the issue here?

PS. I have to use this aws gem for now.

```
/Users/eerdogan/Sites/myApp/config/initializers/devise.rb:17: undefined method `omniauth' for Devise:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/devise-1.1.8/lib/devise.rb:183:in `setup'
    from /Users/eerdogan/Sites/myApp/config/initializers/devise.rb:3
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:201
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:200:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:200
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/eerdogan/Sites/myApp/config/environment.rb:5
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/eerdogan/Sites/myApp/config.ru:3
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
    from /Users/eerdogan/Sites/myApp/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /Users/eerdogan/Sites/myApp/config.ru:1
```

Edit: here is the devise.rb file:

> ```
> # Use this hook to configure devise mailer, warden hooks and so forth. The first
> # four configuration values can also be set straight in your models.
> Devise.setup do |config|
>   config.mailer_sender = "please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com"
>   require 'devise/orm/active_record'
>   config.omniauth :facebook, "1*************", "3******************************"
>   config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]
>   config.stretches = 10
>   config.use_salt_as_remember_token = true
>   config.reset_password_within = 2.hours
> end
> ```

Comment: Also, could you paste the contents of `devise.rb`. The error seems to originate from there.

Comment: Benjamin, Iadded the devise.rb file contents above. Thank you for looking into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `config.facebook` line in `devise.rb` is causing you the grief.

I took a look at my `devise.rb` and I also have another file called `omniauth.rb`.

(1) My `devise.rb` does not have the `config.facebook` line. Try removing that and see if it works.

(2) I have a file called `omniauth.rb`, located in the same directory as `devise.rb`. I'm pasting it below:

```
require 'openid/store/filesystem'

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do

  case Rails.env
  when "development"
    provider :facebook, 'XXX', 'XXXX' , {:scope => 'manage_pages,publish_stream,offline_access,email'}

  when "production"
    provider :facebook, 'XXX', 'XXXX', {:scope => 'manage_pages,publish_stream,offline_access,email', :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => '/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'}}}  
    end
end
```

See if this works out for you. :)

Comment: Benjamin, it looks like you are using a different gem. The gem I have been using is ruby-aaws, and for logistical reasons I am trying to avoid switching it in the short run.

Comment: Very cool, I think this was the issue, seems like version management becomes a problem for repos haven't kept up with most recent Rails. Btw, I ended up switching to a new amazon product advertising api gem, https://github.com/hakanensari/amazon_product, which performs really well and it's fairly flexible. I would recommend it.